# Singular vs. plural hashtags

Tags: tags, blog

I have a channel on [Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_(service)), a messaging app. It's like a blog, where I post messages to my channel subscribers. Which is the best practice to tag a post: #short_story, for example, or #short_stories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit on the *primarily opinion based* side, but think about this: a [hashtag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtag) is a metadata tag that you use to provide a taxonomy to contents. For example, think of a library bookshelf: you will have *hashtags* like Architecture, Drama, Novel, Poetry, and other tags in plural, like Kids, Best Sellers, Classics, and so on.

You’ll notice that IN GENERAL, when the subject has more significance , it goes in singular, and when the subject is more diffuse or it can be included in a broader taxonomy, then it goes in plural. Thus, you may have `Drama —> Best Sellers`.

So, in your case: if your posts include a single story, then it will probably be better to use the **short_story** hashtag. However, if your posts have mixed content, then use the plural